# Terraform Validate Error - Snowflake Automation

Tags: terraform

I am working on self-development to better see how I can implement Infrastructure as Code (Terraform) for a Snowflake Environment.

I have a GitHub repo with GitHub actions configured workflow that does the following:
setups up terraform cloud alongside the following

- Setups up terraform v1.1.2
- Runs Terraform fmt -check
- Terraform validate
- Terraform plan
- Terraform apply

Public Repo https://github.com/waynetaylor/sfguide-terraform-sample/blob/main/.github/workflows/actions.yml here which pretty much is following github actions for terraform cloud steps.

I have configured TF cloud and if I run the terraform validate step this fails with environment variables for snowflake - whether I run locally or remotely via actions. However, if I run a terraform plan and apply and exclude the terraform validate it works.

Example error

```
Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 27, in provider "snowflake":
│   27: provider "snowflake" {
│
│ The argument "account" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [snowflake provider documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/chanzuckerberg/snowflake/latest/docs) suggests that there are three required values: username, account, and region.

Where you call your provider in your code you'll need to provide those values.

e.g.

**from**

```
provider "snowflake" {
  alias = "sys_admin"
  role  = "SYSADMIN"
}
```

**to**

```
provider "snowflake" {
  // required
  username = "..."
  account  = "..."
  region   = "..."

  alias = "sys_admin"
  role  = "SYSADMIN"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I recognize that these are required and have the values set in my terraform cloud workspace. If I comment out the validate in github actions and run plan then the plan and apply run fine.

This tells me that the terraform validate doesn't use the cloud variables like plan and apply do

Comment: This was solved by adding the values you mention. Then creating a variables file and then updating variables from env to terraform variables in TF cloud